# How to ignore a record in query to avoid a conversion error in JOIN?

Tags: t-sql, join, type-conversion

I have a table T1 with alphanumeric codes (varchar column) where always the three first digits will be numeric like this:

```
001ABCD
100EFGH
541XYZZ
OTHER
```

**NOTE: Please notice that I have ONE exception record which is all alpha (OTHER).**

Also I have a table T2 with 3-digit numbers (int column) like this:

```
001
200
300
```

So when I run the following query:

```
SELECT * from T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON SUBSTRING(T1.code1,1,3) = T2.code2
WHERE T1.code1 <> 'OTHER'
```

It is causing me the error:

*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'OTH' to data type int.*

I know the issue but not how to fix it (it's trying to compare 'OTH' with the T2.code2 INT column).
I tried to use WHERE but it didn't work at all.

I cannot get rid of the 'OTHER' record and convert the T2.code2 column from int to varchar is not an option. Any idea?

Comment: you could wrap the substring in the where clause with a try_convert.   So it would be something like `TRY_CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(T1.code1,1,3)) = T2.code2`

Comment: Alternately, you could convert the T2.code2 to CHAR(3). Either way should work.

Comment: Also, it can't be 3 digits AND be an int column. 001 is not an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 different ways you can solve this. I would recommended the persisted computed column since it only has to be calculated on insert and update, not every time you run the read query.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #T1;

CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    Code1 VARCHAR(10)
    ,Code2Computed AS TRY_CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Code1,1,3)) PERSISTED
)
;

CREATE TABLE #T2
(
    Code2 INT
)
;

INSERT INTO #T1
(Code1)
VALUES
('001ABCD')
,('100EFGH')
,('541XYZZ')
,('OTHER')
;

INSERT INTO #T2
(Code2)
VALUES
(001)
,(100)
,(200)
,(300)
,(541)
;

--Convert INT to 3 digit code
SELECT *
FROM #T1
    LEFT JOIN #T2
        ON SUBSTRING(#T1.Code1,1,3) = RIGHT(CONCAT('000',#T2.Code2),3)
;

--Convert 3 digit code to INT
SELECT *
FROM #T1
    LEFT JOIN #T2
        ON TRY_CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(#T1.Code1,1,3)) = #T2.Code2
;

--Use computed column
SELECT *
FROM #T1
    LEFT JOIN #T2
        ON #T1.Code2Computed = #T2.Code2
;
```